# Close actual window with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Using JS I can close the actual window using close method.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Ventana Secundaria</title>
  <script>
        function cerrarse(){
          window.close()
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    Esta es la ventana del popup

    <form>
      <input type=button value="Cerrar" onclick="cerrarse()">
    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

In any Vue.js component I can access to window object but if I use close method nothing happens.... why?

Comment: Did you check the browser console for errors/warnings? Did you make sure the `close()` is actually called?

Comment: Check this article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close there are many conditions for the window to be closed

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript, your script can close only the tabs that were opened by itself. So, first you have to open a new tab, and then you close it.